# Angular: is it possible to share data between scopes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my question is if i can share scopes, for example

i have one function

```
 $scope.init = function(){
        $http({
            url: url_for('account/getinfo'),
            method: "POST",
            data: fields
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {


                $scope.locations = data.stores;


                $scope.currentLocation = data.stores.filter(function(store){

                    return store.mpos_id == $scope.mposid;
                });

                if ($scope.currentLocation.length > 0) {
                    $scope.currentLocation = $scope.currentLocation[0];
                }


            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            });


    };
```

the $scope.currentLocation is an Object!
 can i use this obj data in other function?

tried with angular.copy and extend, no success

```
$scope.getInfo = function(){
  $scope.currentLocationData = angular.copy($scope.currentLocation);
}
```

Comment: what do you expect from the function?

Comment: i want to send currentLocation parameters to data base from different function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services in Angular are singletons, so you could store this data in a service and inject it wherever you need it. It's already considered best practice to separate your data requests into services, so you'd be creating a service anyways.

**Here's an example:**

First separate your data retrieval logic into a service.

```
angular.module('app').service('accountDataService', AccountDataService);

function AccountDataService($http){
    var service = this;

    service.getInfo = function(fields){ 
        return $http.post(url_for('account/getinfo'), fields)
            .then(function(response){ return response.data.stores; });
    }
}
```

Then create an account service to share the retrieved data between controllers/components:

```
angular.module('app').service('accountService', AccountService);

function AccountService(accountDataService){
    var service = this;

    service.currentLocation = {};
    service.locations = [];

    service.init = function(fields, mposid){ 

        accountDataService.getInfo(fields).then(function(stores){
            service.locations = stores;

            var currentLocations = stores.filter(function(store){
                return store.mpos_id == mposid;
            });

            if (currentLocations.length > 0) {
                service.currentLocation = currentLocations[0];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do in your controllers is inject the `accountService`.

```
angular.module('app').run(function(accountService){
    accountService.init({ /* your fields */ }, '[your mposid]');
});

angular.module('app').controller('myController', MyController);

function MyController($scope, accountService){
    $scope.currentLocation = accountService.currentLocation;
}
```

*Running the `init` function inside `run(..)` is just for example. You'd preferably run this in a route resolve function or something like that due to the async nature of the init function.*

---

***Bonus note***

Avoid using the `$scope` to pass variables to the view. Use the `controllerAs` syntax instead. You can check the documentation for more info on how it works, or I suggest you to [check out the angular 1.x style guide from John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can copy like that i will work. you can check in below example.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 <body>

 <div ng-app ="app" ng-controller ="ctrl">
    
{{currentLocationData}}

    </div>
 <script>
 angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    
 
 $scope.currentLocation = 'testing angular copy';
    $scope.currentLocationData = angular.copy($scope.currentLocation);
   
 
})

 </script> 

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: tried allready, im trying to share between two function, and getting empty object

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to **share** data between two controllers / directives, then you should use a **service** and inject it in both the controllers / directives.

If you are looking to just create a new copy of / clone the object, then you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.currentLocation))`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can access that object in another scope if and only if that scope is a child not isolated of the previous one. In this case your child scope will inherit all the properties of the parent scope too.

So if that code is the scope of a controller, and you have another controller as child of that one, the child one can access that property.

Although it works, a lot of times that's not the best practice to develop things using AngularJS. It will force a dependency among the two controllers and if you will change your code, you could lose the inheritance and break your code.

In these cases the best solution is to define a service which holds the value of the `currentLocation`. Then inject this service wherever you need to access this value.

I hope it makes sense